# EntityManagerFactoryWrapper cannot be cast to SessionFactoryImplementor

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, jpa-2.1

I am trying to learn jpa multitenant on java ee 7. I am following this tutorial.

```
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/06/15/jakarta-ee-multitenancy-with-jpa-on-wildfly-part-1/
```

But I am getting below error:

```
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:662)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
... 125 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper cannot be cast to org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl
at net.rhuanrocha.dao.Dao.getEntityManager(Dao.java:21)
at net.rhuanrocha.dao.JobDao.findAll(JobDao.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Inside Dao.java -> getEntityManager()

My Maven dependencies are as below:

1. javax javaee-web-api 7.0 provided
2. org.hibernate hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.7.Final jar

I am using Glassfish 4.1 as server and JDK 8.
The imports are as below:

1. import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
2. import org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl;
3. import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
4. import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
5. import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

Answer (score 1):

This works. The back-end I used was Jakarta EE 8, Hibernate 5.4 and Payara 2021. I think your version should work too.

```
import com.dao.multitenancy.MultitenancyResolver;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
//import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;

/**
 *
 * @author Peter
 */
public abstract class Dao {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public EntityManager getEM(final String tenantId) {

        //EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory();
       final SessionFactoryImplementor sf = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class);
          
        final MultitenancyResolver tenantResolver = (MultitenancyResolver) sf.getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver();
        tenantResolver.setTenantIdentifier(tenantId);

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

Ref: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-interceptors